# Is it possible to disable page caching on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, disk, io, caching

I am running an application on Ubuntu 20.04 which requires me to clear the page cache everytime I run it. Currently, I just run `echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` everytime before I run the application. I'll need to run this application multiple times. Is there anyway to disable page caching on my system?

Answer (score 0):

Please give this a try: https://github.com/Feh/nocache

This may or may not work for you because in some situations you cannot disable disk cache.